# Three.js: displaying a <div> over a canvas with skybox

Tags: html, css, canvas, three.js, skybox

I created a skybox on a Three.js canvas like this:

```
var urls = [
  'pos-x.jpg',
  'neg-x.jpg',
  'pos-y.jpg',
  'neg-y.jpg',
  'pos-z.jpg',
  'neg-z.jpg'
]
window.cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
window.shader = THREE.ShaderLib['cube']; 
shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; 

window.skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
  vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
  uniforms: shader.uniforms,
  depthWrite: false,
  side: THREE.BackSide
});

window.skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000),
  skyBoxMaterial
);

skybox.position.set(0, 0, 0);

scene.add(skybox);
```

My problem is that any 'div' I try to add above the canvas is hidden behind the skybox whatever z-index I give it. They show up if I do not add the skybox. Does anybody know why and how to fix it?

Comment: Your question is confusing: The canvas is displaying the skybox, not hidden behind it. And your title mentions a div, but your question text does not mention it. Please clarify.

Comment: The div word was in my original text but was not displayed. I remove the html container and it is fine now. To be clearer, I have a Three.js canvas IN which I display the skybox. When I try to put a div ABOVE the canvas, it does not appear, unless I remove the skybox or I add {transform: translate(0px, 0px); display: inline-block;} in the div css. I really can not see what is causing this.

Comment: I do this all the time. I can't write a proper answer right now (no time), but here is an example that works: http://rwoodley.org/MyContent/WIP/37-SkyDomeFUn/main.html. Are you trying to add the divs via JS or in HTML directly?

Comment: The divs are declared in HTML and populated in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the divs after the Three.js canvas tag in the HTML body and it worked.

Comment: i have same problem in react skybox canvas hide a div ? how do you fixed that ?